# What OS would you choose for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, operating-system

What OS would you choose for Visual Studio 2010?

I have been running Vista for VS 2008 with a Virtual PC running Vista for VS 2010 Beta 2.
(I didnt want to run them side by side)

Now that VS2010 is launched, I want to re-install my machine (2.2 GHz Dell XPS laptop with 4Gb Ram) , should I load Vista or sould I try out Windows 7?

I am devoping with asp.net MVC, Silverlight and WCF? Note sure what OS version has a better version of IIS to support these?

I realise this may be subjective, but would like to hear peoples views...

Comment: Win7 is great, all up and running with VS2010. One slight issue with debugging asp.net app with skype installed (see this link http://www.codeattest.com/blogs/martin/2006/06/server-committed-protocol-violation.html) also needed to run devenv under the admin account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was up to me, I would go for Win7 x64 for a host, with as much memory as I could afford, and use virtual machines to represent the server (and desktop) platforms I am targetting. Hosting on Server 2008? Fire up a Server 2008 VM. Database is SQL 2005 on Server 2003? Add a VM...

Otherwise, with <= 4 gig RAM, Win7 x86; my (slightly old) laptop works *much* better on Win 7 than it ever did (same laptop) on XP / Vista.

I also tend to find that VMWare Player (Workstation if you have the cash) works better for me than either Microsoft Virtual PC or Windows Virtual PC.

Comment: Interesting you say Win7 is better than XP/Vista, my laptop is also slightly old, so may try out Win 7 on that basis...

Comment: @Mark - I did just that; bought a new HDD so I could try it without wiping (and besides, a new bigger faster HDD may be worthwhile anyway)